# Trying to get items from a file into a list

Tags: python, list, file, file-handling

I'm trying to get the items from a file into 4 different lists
firstname
surname
group
password
I've tried some ways but they haven't worked, mainly:

```
myfile = (file.readline())
f = myfile.split(",")
x = 0
while x < len(f):
  firstname = [f[x]]
  x += 1
  surname = [f[x]]
  x += 1
  group = [f[x]]
  x += 1
  password = [f[x]]
  x += 1
print(firstname)
```

But this only would print out the last name in the file which is "Eren". Here are the contents of the file:
`Angela,Rich,Adult,Twinkle$,Siraj,Adkins,Junior,Password123%,Stefano,Love,Senior,Qwerty#,Cameron,Wilder,Junior,Wildtime$,Griff,Sutherland,Adult,Geordieman2%,Amaan,Sosa,Senior,Mollymoo5#,Isaak,Schroeder,Junior,Christmas#,Nana,Galloway,Junior,TheGrinch$,Lila,Blanchard,Adult,Tigger27$,Eren,Acosta,Adult,Jamjar1992#`

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At every iteration you are rewriting the list. So in the end you will have only the last record. You should use the .append () method instead. Something like that:

```
myfile = (file.readline())
f = myfile.split(",")

#Initialize the lists
firstname=[]
surname=[]
group=[]
password=[]

x = 0
while x < len(f):
  firstname.append(f[x])
  x += 1
  surname.append([f[x])
  x += 1
  group.append(f[x])
  x += 1
  password.append(f[x])
  x += 1
print(firstname)
```